# Eliminar background cuando el usuario ejecute el script

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer un fondo "dinámico", la idea es:

El index.html tiene que tener un fondo, este fondo debe tener una imagen, como un logotipo. Este logo debe aparecer hasta que el usuario intente navegar y acceda a algún enlace, este enlace llamará a un script interno que cargará un contenido dentro del resultado div.

El problema no puedo hacer que esto suceda, hasta ahora llego a la viceversa, pero por supuesto no lo que estoy buscando.

Aquí está el código html.

```css
<!--CSS-->

body {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 background-image: url("imagenes/logo.jpg");
 background-size: 25%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
 border-style: solid none none none;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

    <body>
<div class="navigation-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div id="main-menu-container">
        <div id="main-menu" class="nav">
          <li class="menuparent">
            <a>MENU</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a id="page7">First option, same block</a></li>
              <li><a id="page9">Second option, same block</a></li>
              <li><a id="page10">Third option, same block</a></li>
            </ul>
          </body>

<!-- El Script -->

<div id="result">
    <script src="./docu2_files/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>        
</div>
```

Comment: `...un fondo, este fondo debe tener una imagen, como un logotipo`, ¿tienes alguna página de referencia, es decir, una página que tenga el comportamiento que estás buscando?

Comment: No, pero quizas puedas simplificarlo....Al cargar una pagina web esa web tiene un <body> y dentro de este un <div>, el div contiene una imagen cualquiera. Pero a su vez tambien contiene un script, un script relacionado a unos botones que el usuario puede hacer "click", al hacer esto provoca una accion que recoge todo el contenido de otros documentos html y los pone en dicho <div> en el proceso elimina la imagen y solo deja el contenido de los otros documentos .html.

Comment: Dices que la imagen está en un div dentro de body, pero en tu código lo muestras directamente en el body. No hallo concordancia entre lo que dices y tu código. Sé más explícito al explicar tu problema y el resultado que esperas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es hacer algún cambio en el css de un elemento con un evento jQuery es más que suficiente.

```
$("#elementoQueDisparaElEvento").click(function(){
    $("#elementoAlQueLeQuieresCambiarElBackground").css("background", "red"); //Hará que cuando des clic en el elemento que dispara el evento (puedes ser cualquiera, digamos un li) el background de tu elemento cambiará a colo rojo.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, esta podría ser una, entre varias, formas de hacerlo, usando jQuery.

El HTML y el CSS has de adaptarlo a tus necesidades...

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/4gb7u37d/9/)

```js
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() { 
     $('.main-content').addClass("hide-bg");
});
```

```css
<!--Código CSS:-->

.mainPage {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}

.main-content {
 background:  url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/tundephoto/tundephoto1003/tundephoto100300111/6647645-sample-background-Stock-Photo.jpg')
  no-repeat center;
 width: 600px;
 height: 450px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content.hide-bg {
    background: none;
}

.text-content {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!--Código HTML:-->
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
 <div class="mainPage">
  <div class="main-content">
   <div id="clickme" class="text-content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Uno</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tres</a></li>
         </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>


<!--Código jQuery (librería Javascript):

Simplemente, al hacer click, se agrega la clase `hide-bg` a la clase `main-content`, que ejecuta `background: none;`, ocultando la imagen de fondo.-->
```

Comment: Tu jsfiddle me apareció sin código JS.

Comment: @amenadiel Hubo un error, pero ya funciona, tanto el fiddle como aquí mismo, usando el botón Ejecutar. :)